# How do you map an array to colour a fill choropleth map?

Tags: mapbox, mapbox-gl-js

I am trying to manually map a geojson fill layer with 6 entries to an array of colors. I tried the following but it doesn't work.

Basically was hoping that the colour be countrypalette[id]

I tried countrypalette["get", "id"], but that doesn't work either.

```
const countrypalette = ["#f0d27e", "#789d23", "#c06e51", "#b3e467", "#84241a", "#d9c0c7"]

 map.addLayer(
            {
              id: 'Mekong_countries',
              type: 'fill',
              source: 'Mekong_countries',
              paint: {
                "fill-color": ["at", "id", ["array", countrypalette]]
              }
            }
          )
```

Comment: You need to include a sample of your data. What does the `id` attribute contain?

Comment: They are just iterations; 1, 2, 3, 4, etc.

Comment: Please include a sample of your data.

Answer (score 0):

You are missing a property lookup for your `id` (I guess it's an integer property of your features). The second thing is a bit odd, it seems like we need to at a `to-color` conversion function to make this work:

```
["to-color", ["at", ["get", "id"], ["literal", COUNTRY_PALETTE]]]
```

In your code:

```js
const COUNTRY_PALETTE = ["#f0d27e", "#789d23", "#c06e51", "#b3e467", "#84241a", "#d9c0c7"]

map.addLayer({
    id: 'Mekong_countries',
    type: 'fill',
    source: 'Mekong_countries',
    paint: {
        "fill-color": [
              "to-color", ["at", ["get", "id"], ["literal", COUNTRY_PALETTE]]
        ]
    }
});
```

It seems like adding the `to-color` is mandatory, otherwise mapbox complains about a type error. The bug is described in [this issue](https://github.com/mapbox/mapbox-gl-js/issues/8713).